# Can I hide the "Currently In game" from Steam?

Tags: steam

I don't want to hide my online status.
I want to hide the currently in-game which appears on a game on my profile page.
Any way to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Go in to your profile, and hit edit profile. There's a privacy settings at the left menu, inside that settings there's a setting called "Game Details".

> This category includes the list of all games on your Steam account, games you’ve wishlisted, your achievements and your playtime. **This setting also controls whether you’re seen as "in-game" and the title of the game you are playing.**

(emphasis mine)

Set this to either Friends only (the info is visible to only your friends) or Private (the info won't be shared with anyone).